# Domain driven design and file storage

Tags: c#, repository, domain-driven-design, factory

I'm developing an application which allows users to copy movies from one location to their user account. For this, the movie will need to be copied to the user's personal folder.

The problem I'm facing is, is *when* to actually copy the file over. At the moment, I have a MovieFactory that after creation, immediately puts it into the MovieRepository after the factory method has done the copying. This seems to work fine.

The repository and factory, however, should not have to know of each other. Ideally I would do this:

```
var movie = this.MovieFactory.CreateFromFile(new FileInfo("MyPhoto.mp4"));
this.MovieRepository.Add(movie);
```

Now my idea was to do the copying inside the `Add` method, given you're basically copying into the repository itself. However, by doing so, the movie's file location will change as well. As a result, the `Add` method either has to modify `movie` or return a new, but different movie instance. This sounds like code smell to me, and I'm completely stuck on this scenario.

At the moment of speaking, the file location does not get stored. Instead, the location gets deduced from multiple other movie properties using a MovieFileLocator service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the question has DDD tag, I will answer in more DDD terminology:

- You create a `Movie` aggregate using the factory `CreateFromFile` method
- Inside this factory method you definitely call some constructor and/or methods of the `Movie`
- You can dispatch a *domain event* `MovieCreatedFromFile` and in the handler do whatever you want to do (copy file to the user's folder)
- You continue the application service method flow by adding your aggregate to a repository

How exactly domain event dispatching and handling will work - it is up to you. Since this is infrastructure-related work, I would dispatch it outside of the current unit of work. You can use something lightweight like [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/) for this. By this you ensure your aggregate is the transaction boundary but be prepared to handle file copying errors when it (unlikely) happens. This "preparation" might just include notification and manual work since it will probably never happen.

Answer (score 0):

So the location depends on several properties of the movie. You want to move the movie, meaning you want to modify a property of the movie. You should do the copying then, I guess. Something like MovieRepository.Add(movie); movie.LocationProperty=Locations.NewLocation (and here you would do the actual moving of the file)

Comment: Considering you are abstracting the location, the copying itself could become unnecessary, as the physical location might become irrelevant and only the properties of the movie matter.

Comment: The problem however, is that the location is dependent on whether the movie has actually been put in the repository or not. If it's been put in, the location points to somewhere in a user folder. If it's not in the repository, the location is still the original source like a USB drive.

Comment: So just adding the item to a repository changes the item, that is what bothers you and brings a code smell. It seems to me that it is exactly what you should change. However, if you think about it as two different types of movie classes, let's say OriginalContent and ImportedMovie, then an operation like `ImportedMovie movie=repo.Import(OriginalContent)` would make sense, as there is no relation between the original class and the resulting imported movie. This would probably solve also the problem of instantly changing a property and then having to wait a few seconds to copy the file.

Answer (score 0):

You have two objects which lie within an application layer. If I understand right, by copying is meant a domain logic of assigning a movie to a user.

In that case, you should create domain service for the process accepting the movie and the user. This domain service should inject an object with an interface for handling movie manipulation and call something like `movie.assignTo(user.id)`. This way you explicitly reveal the assigning and separate the domain logic from infrastructure logic.